# java Buffered image gray level

Tags: java, image

after converting a java image into grayscale and making some manipulation(average filter for example) on the image the new value of the rgb is transformed into a colored pixel.

example 

i have buffered image.
transform into grayLevelImage
adding * pixel sum(getRGB)/9 will create new rgb which is color not gray
 so how to preserve the value as gray level?
or is there a java object that work only on gray level not on colored image such that the value of the pixel is from 0 --> to 255 with out any colored attrribute.

**edit**
suppose i have the color(x1,y1,z1)  c1 which have the rgb value of u1

and we have the color(x2,y2,z2) c2 which have the rgb of u2

if we transformed the c1 to g1 and c2 to g2 (the gray transformation ofthe color)

if we added (g1.getRGB()+g2.getRGB())/2; the new color is not gray it is colored again (error value) and that is due to rgb value of color is an integer that represent r , g and b values

Comment: what kind of libraries do you use? add your attempts in order to get help. your question is unclear.

Comment: no special library, the buffered image class in java. and the problem is simple if you get the averge of two rgb of gray pixels you will not get a gray pixel since the new rgb value might reflect a colored pixel.

Comment: i can use the averge of red, green , blue one by one and will give a good result. but that cannot be done when working on histogram transformation

Comment: I found your question confusing.  It sounds like you should clone the gray image before converting it to the color one.

Comment: Can't you just convert the final image (after the manipulations) into a greyscale one?

Comment: no can't image after manipulation is wrong ..